# Oracle migration unable to create indexes

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, impdp, expdp

I want to move the contents of a database instance to another using the expdp and impdp utilities. The source instance is version 12.1.0.1.0 and the destination is 11.2.0.1.0 so I modified the expdp command to include the version:

```
expdp system@db1/pass schemas=main directory=dmpdir dumpfile=backup-26-11-2015.dmp logfile=backup-26-11-2015.log version=11.2.0.1.0
```

However when I try to import this dmp file into the 11.2 instance it copies everything except for indexes with this error:

```
ORA-39083: Object type INDEX failed to create with error:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_INDEX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Failing sql is:
BEGIN 
ctxsys.driimp.create_index('ACTCI_T1DX','ACTCI',USER,
'','1','DESCRIPTION','1',
'100','0','8130','1',
'LANGCODE',NULL, NULL, 0,'Y',NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);


ctxsys.driimp.set_object('DATASTORE','DIRECT_DATASTORE',0);

ctxsys.driimp.set_object('DATATYPE','CHAR_DATATY
```

I've noticed that the ending line is missing some code and I'm seeing this occur for every error thrown. Why is the statement cutting off like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, and it will be fixed in a future version.

Use `CTX_REPORT.CREATE_INDEX_SCRIPT` to generate the index scripts, and create them manually.

Comment: `all_indexes` only lists 277 indexes, so obviously doing this is completely feasible and not at all a waste of time.